# No translator error while running Apache Beam job on Flink cluster

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I created a very simple apache beam job for test, it is written in scala and looks like this:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args: _*).create()
    val p = Pipeline.create(options)

    println(s"--------> $options")

    val printDoFn = new DoFn[String, Void] {
      @ProcessElement
      def processElement(c: ProcessContext): Unit = {
        val e = c.element()
        logger.info(e)
        println(s"===> $e")
      }
    }

    p.apply(Create.of[String]("A", "B", "CCC"))
      .apply(ParDo.of(printDoFn))

    p.run()
  }
}
```

Now I deployed a flink cluster with the official flink docker image.

I created a uber-jar of my test program using maven shaded plugin.

I uploaded this uber-jar with the web UI interface of Job Manager.

I login into the JobManager machine, and find the uploaded uber-jar, and I run the job with:

```
flink run -c myapps.Test \
 ./52649b36-aa57-4f2b-95c7-2552fd737ea6_pipeline_beam-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
 --runner=FlinkRunner
```

But I got this error:

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:545)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:420)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:404)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:798)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:289)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:215)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1035)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$9(CliFrontend.java:1111)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1111)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No translator known for org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$Bounded
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.PTransformTranslation.urnForTransform(PTransformTranslation.java:164)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.visitPrimitiveTransform(FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.java:93)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:657)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:649)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:649)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:311)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:245)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:458)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineTranslator.translate(FlinkPipelineTranslator.java:38)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.translate(FlinkBatchPipelineTranslator.java:49)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.translate(FlinkPipelineExecutionEnvironment.java:119)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner.run(FlinkRunner.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:313)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:299)
    ...
```

I think the key error is: `No translator known for org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$Bounded`

I compiled my program with apache beam 2.7.0, and from the flink runner page: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/ , I deployed flink 1.5.5 version, with the flink official image: `flink:1.5.5-hadoop28-scala_2.11-alpine`

I couldn't find any useful information on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I write the maven pom file myself, and I do the shaded plugin my self and I missed this section in shaded plugin:

```
<transformers>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
</transformers>
```

Now it works.